# Install BigBlueButton 0.9 in CentOS 6+

Tags: centos6.5, bigbluebutton

I have been looking around for the installation steps for BigBlueButton 0.9 in CentOS version 6+ without any results. I have only been provided installation steps for BigBlueButton 0.6. Any directions where I can get the installation details for BBB 0.9 in CentOS 6+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so far i have not seen BBB installation steps for  CentOS however, you can surely able to install Docker on CentOS for BBB.

Answer (score 0):

You easily install bigbluebbutton on centos by simply installing all the open source components separately first.

You can find the open source components here,http://bigbluebutton.org/components/

After that, install the webapps to bigbluebutton web and bigbluebutton app.

Configure the bigbluebutton.propreties in the web, create the ruby god conf file to allow record and play back, create the needed directories and setup the nginx config.

All these tasks are simple by them selves, but this process will take you a few days.

It took me a 2 days to install 0.81 on centos, so i can definitely guarantee that it is possible and doable without any extra needed applications.